# Bulk Update - Oracle Sequence

Tags: oracle, updates

I have a table with 150 million records
I want to update the sequence column from a sequence.

What is the fastest way to update?
I have used parallel, but it is taking hours and not ending

```
UPDATE /+ parallel (c, 50)/ rpm_future_retail_tmp c
SET future_retail_id = rpm_future_retail_seq.NEXTVAL;
```

what is the faster way?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have cascading FKs on that column "future_retail_id" ?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly creating a new table is faster than applying a DML, especially faster than an UPDATE statement. You can use as an alternative :

```
CREATE TABLE rpm_future_retail_tmp_ parallel 8 nologging AS
SELECT rpm_future_retail_seq.NEXTVAL AS future_retail_id,
       <and the comma-separated columns other than future_retail_id>
  FROM rpm_future_retail_tmp; 

DROP TABLE rpm_future_retail_tmp;
ALTER TABLE rpm_future_retail_tmp_ RENAME TO rpm_future_retail_tmp;
```

where

- the degree of parallelism might vary depending on your DBMS's source
- the statements to reproduce later the privileges(grants) and indexes should
  be saved to a place for the table(`rpm_future_retail_tmp`) before
  dropping it

Answer (score 1):

If sequence starts from 1, then you might also consider updating column with a `ROWNUM` value instead.

This is my 21cXE database, running on MS Windows 10, Intel i5, 8GB RAM. I have a table with ~1 million rows (don't feel like creating one 150 times larger):

```
SQL> select count(*) from rpm;

  COUNT(*)
----------
   1033616

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
```

Updating it with a sequence takes ~12 seconds:

```
SQL> update rpm set id = seq.nextval;

1033616 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:12.98
SQL> update rpm set id = seq.nextval;

1033616 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:12.39
SQL> update rpm set id = seq.nextval;

1033616 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:10.56
```

Let's try `rownum`; it takes *less* time (average of 3 runs is ~4 seconds):

```
SQL> update rpm set id = rownum;

1033616 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:07.51
SQL> update rpm set id = rownum;

1033616 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.89
SQL> update rpm set id = rownum;

1033616 rows updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:02.87
SQL>
```

---

I understand that your system is different from mine and timings *depend* on various things, but I guess it can't harm if you try another approach.

For future inserts into the ID column (via database trigger?), just (re)create the sequence:

```
SQL> select max(id) from rpm;

   MAX(ID)
----------
   1033616

SQL> drop sequence seq;

Sequence dropped.

SQL> create sequence seq start with 1033617;

Sequence created.

SQL>
```